# PHP: Create a simple log in form without MySQL

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm trying to mess around with a simple log in form, that is just for fun. The content is nothing sensitive, but I'm trying to learn `SESSION` and such. I've created this simple login form, that works fine, but if a user clicks the `"home"` button which is `href'd` to `process_login.php`, they are asked to login again. I'm trying to save the `username` and `password` it in a `SESSION` so if they login, and hit `home` from any page, it will remember their log in information and not ask them to continuously log in.

I have a `form.php` script, that uses the `POST` method, with two `textfields`, the username and password are saved as "admin" in the `process_login.php`, and if they match the `POST` `indices` from the form, then i'll include `content.php`. In `process_login.php` I take the `POST` data and run it like so :

```
SESSION_start();
//var_dump($_POST);
$match_username = 'admin' ;
$match_password = 'admin';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($username == $match_username && $password == $match_password ){
        include 'content.php';
    }elseif($username == "" || $password != $match_password){
        echo "Please try again.";
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])){
        //Run if not set
        $_SESSION["logged_in"] = array(1 => array($username => $_POST['username'], $password => $_POST['password']));
    };
};
```

You'll see above that I'm trying to set the SESSION information, but I know i'm not doing it correctly. Once a user logs in, everything works. But if that same user clicks on "home," from another page, it will tell them to "`Please try again.`" I'd like to let the user stay logged in once they are logged in.

All advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just an HTML button below everything with href="process_login.php"

Comment: Make sure you also have similar sessions code in "home".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test of `$_SESSION["logged_in"]` should not be inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` block.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    include 'content.php';
    exit();
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($username == $match_username && $password == $match_password ){
        $_SESSION["logged_in"] = array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'password => $_POST['password']);
        include 'content.php';
        exit();
} elseif($username == "" || $password != $match_password){
    echo "Please try again.";
}
// Put login form here
```

I changed your `$_SESSION["logged_in"]` variable. Now it's just a one-dimensional array instead of 2-dimensional, and the keys are the words `username` and `password` -- it doesn't make much sense to use variables as keys there.

Comment: I think `$username => $_POST['username']` as an array element is kinda creepy. But still it can exist.

Comment: I didn't even notice that. I noticed that it had an extra dimension, but didn't think it was important enough to fix. But now I've fixed the keys, and removed the dimension while I was at it.

Comment: Works perfect. I changed the first line to $_SESSION from $_POST. Thank you @Barmar 

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    include 'content.php';
    exit();
}

Comment: And I added the " ' " after the key password.